# Bind Kendo UI Grid to CRUD REST API

Tags: rest

I would like to bind a Restful CRUD API that i have created via PHP and runs locally without problem to a Kendo UI Grid but unfortunately no data is displayed into grid.

I have got the following code to display the departments of a company

```
<head>
    <title>Διαχείριση  Επαφών</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/kendo.default.min.css">
    <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/kendo.web.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="contacts"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){


            var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

                    autoSync: true,

                    transport: {
                                    read    : {
                                    url     : 'http://localhost/contact/api/read.php',
                                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                                    type: 'GET'
                                }
                            },

                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                id: { type: "number" },
                                name: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        },
                        data: function (response) {
                           return response.Data;
                       }
                    }

                 });



           $("#contacts").kendoGrid({

               dataSource:remoteDataSource,
               pageable: true,
               columns: [
                {field:"id", title: "Department ID", width: "20px"},
                {field: "name", title: "Department", width: "60px"}
               ]
           });



        });

    </script>

</body>
```

and my restful api returns the following json data via `"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"` in PHP

```
{"records":[{"id":"1","name":"SALES"},{"id":"2","name":"STAFF"}]}
```

Any idea that could assist me why the data are not displayed at all into grid?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

dataType: 'json' and 
json data must be like this: [{"id":"1","name":"SALES"},{"id":"2","name":"STAFF"}]